# How to sort a python list bidirectionally, by numbers in descending order and by alphabets in ascending order?

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort a list which has tuples consisting of a word and a number.

```
my_list = [('hello',25), ('hell',4), ('bell',4)]
```

How can i sort this (using lambda maybe) so that i get

```
[('hello',25), ('bell',4), ('hell',4)]
```

Comment: Will you please explain what problem u are facing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to take advantage of [sort stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts) and do the sort in two passes:

```
>>> lot = [('hello', 25), ('hell', 4), ('bell', 4)]
>>> lot.sort(key=lambda r: r[0])
>>> lot.sort(key=lambda r: r[1], reverse=True)
>>> lot
[('hello', 25), ('bell', 4), ('hell', 4)]
```

You can also do this with [*sorted()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> lot = [('hello', 25), ('hell', 4), ('bell', 4)]
>>> sorted(sorted(lot, key=lambda r: r[0]), key=lambda r: r[1], reverse=True)
[('hello', 25), ('bell', 4), ('hell', 4)]
```

This is the technique recommended in Python's [Sorting Howto](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the transformation within the `key` argument to `sorted` to achieve the ordering you want.

```
x = [('hello',25),('hell',4),('bell',4)]

sorted(x, key = lambda tup: (-tup[1], tup[0]))
Out[15]: [('hello', 25), ('bell', 4), ('hell', 4)]
```

Comment: While this works in this case, it isn't a general purpose solution that applies well to other cases. (for example, you can't use the technique for sort strings descending; it only works for the numbers).